# Follow only certain links with Wget but download every host from those links

Tags: wget

So, let's say I want to mirror a site with Wget. I want wget to follow and download all the links from http://www.example.com/example/ or http://example.example.com/. How can I do this? I tried this command but it doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to work.

```
wget -r --mirror -I '/example' -H -D'example.example.com' 'https://www.example.com/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with 'https://www.example.com/', want to save files from 'http://www.example.com/example/' and 'http://example.example.com/` ?

Then leave away -H. -I is ambiguous here - does it apply to both domains or just the first ? And btw, -r is included in --mirror.

Check out --accept-regex and --reject-regex for a finer-grained control, e.g. --accept-regex="(www.example.com/example/|example.example.com/)".